# Order by case SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order(Descendant) the milestones table by looking at the second column.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ("folo", "keo@off.mp");
INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ("kj", "apm@off.mp");
INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ("sapi", "smsp@off.mp");

CREATE TABLE milestones(id INT, title TEXT,name TEXT);
INSERT INTO milestones (id, title, name) VALUES (429944, "3", "4");
INSERT INTO milestones (id, title, name) VALUES (429943, "4", "5");

SELECT id, title, name FROM milestones ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN id = id THEN 2 END)
DESC;
```

This code should give me that :

```
  id    |   title   |    name
-----------------------------
429943         4         5
429944         3         4
```

But it gives me that :

```
  id    |   title   |    name
-----------------------------
429944         3         4
429943         4         5
```

I tried everything but I can't sort by second column. Can you help me please ?

Comment: its simple an [order by title desc], your case statement is returning nothing but only 2.

Comment: if title is going to always be a number, use a numeric column type.   Otherwise, a sort() operator is going to do an alphabetic sort and you'll need to cast it back to a number.   You'll need to supply what kind of SQL engine you are using to get help on that.

Comment: Why don't you look at the result of `CASE` in `SELECT` like `SELECT id, title, name, CASE WHEN id = id THEN 2 END FROM milestones ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN id = id THEN 2 END)
DESC;` to see what are you ordering it by first. I'm certain that will return you `2` all the way.. so what's to order when your value to order is all the same?

Comment: The `sql-injection` tag doesn't apply to this Q. Really should be an `insert`.

Comment: Why not use `order by title desc`, its more follow able than the very obscure (but supported syntax) of `order by 2 desc`

Comment: It took me a while to understand why you expected your expression to sort the results by title. You expected the 2 to be treated as a position. It isn't. It is treated as a mere numeric value, which is the same for every row, so no sorting takes place at all. Positions in `ORDER BY` only work stand-alone. As soon as it is an expression, e.g. `ORDER BY 1 + 1` or `ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = id THEN 2 END`, this is no position but a number value. And like many others, I don't like positions in `ORDER BY`; I always use the name.

Comment: Other than null, under what circumstances do you imagine id wouldn't equal id?

Comment: I choosed  case of  ```id = id``` because I know it is always true to test ```order by Case...``` . But in my project the condition in the case is not trivial like this.

Comment: @BretWeinraub I am using SQLite. When I put ``` order by 2 desc ```, the sort() work. So it is not a problem of column type. I just have an issue to make the order by work with a ```case``` statement

Comment: @ThorstenKettner So why is it working for ```order by 2 desc``` ? Is  not ```2``` also a numerical value  ?

Comment: That is the exeption I mentioned. As a standalone number, this works as a position in `ORDER BY`. I just wouldn't use it at all, so there is no more confusion about when 2 means 2 and when 2 means title :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I find this a bit strange. I think it's a tricky property of SQL.

Comment: Yes, there are things in SQL that one shouldn't use. Positional `ORDER BY` may be one of these things, Another, much more serious, is definitely `NATURAL JOIN`, because it can render queries faulty that once worked properly. Another is `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` just for the reason that it can make a query very hard to read. There's probably more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below -

```
SELECT id, title, name FROM milestones ORDER BY title desc
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate query to try.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM milestones t1
ORDER BY t1.title DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT id, title, name FROM milestones 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Ordering at the 2nd column. Here's a demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00757414b3f0ba691b9f7bb488e70bcf

However, I'm interested to know why you use `CASE` in the `ORDER`. If there's something else you're trying to achieve [please update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64998130/edit).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I want to use a ```case``` in the ```order by``` statement , if I put ```order by 2``` it works. I just want the ```order by case ...``` to work.

Comment: As I'm reading the comments, I'm guessing the full `CASE` description would be something like `CASE WHEN (this condition) THEN (order by) (this column) END` where `(this column)` is not written as the column name - instead it's the position of the column... is that correct?

Comment: I see. I doubt that this function is available - at least in MySQL/MariaDB - but I admit it's quite interesting.

Comment: I verified in MySQL, it does not work. I will try in MariaDB.

Comment: How are you doing the testing? You install it locally or using online fiddle like https://dbfiddle.uk ?